# React Error: Error: Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs

Earlier today, I tried running create-react-app, but I got an error about templates and how my version of React may be out of date. So I removed React globally and then reinstalled. I ran create-react-app again and it started working again.

I was trying to create an app afterwards but I keep getting the following message:

×
Error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
>   components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
>   object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's
>   defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

I never got this message before while using React. Here is my code so far:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import UserOutput from './Components/UserOutput';
import UserInput from './Components/UserInput'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <UserInput />
        <UserOutput username="Test" />


      </div>
    )
  }
};

export default App;
```

UserOutput.js

```
import React from 'react';

function UserOutput(props) {
  return <h1>this is my username: {props.username} </h1>;
}

export default UserOutput;
```

UserInput.js

```
import React from 'react';

function UserInput() {
    return <input>Name</input>
};

export default UserInput;
```

I tried searching for a fix for my error, but could not find a solution. I believe I am importing everything correctly and it complies without error in my IDE, but I get the error in my browser.

Comment: Might be related to the fact that `<input>` is self-closing (so `<input value="Name" />`)

Comment: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.